# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> "

Tags: bash, unix

```
./ex6.bash: 줄 10: ((: > : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> ")
```

And this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Input first number => "
read num1
printf "Input second number => "
read num2

num1=$a1
num2=$a2
if (( $a1>$a2 ))
then
    while [ $a1==$a2 ];
    do
        let "a1 = $a1 - 1"
        let "a2 = $a2 + 1"
        if (( $a1==$a2 ))
        then
            printf " $num2 ~ $num1 mid point : $a1 \n"
            break
        elif (( $((a1 -1))==$a2 ))
        then
            printf " $num2 ~ $num1 mid point : $a1 \n"
            break
        fi
    done
else
    while [ $a1==$a2 ];
    do
        let "a1 = $a1 + 1"
        let "a2 = $a2 - 1"
        if (( $a1==$a2 ))
        then
            printf " $num1 ~ $num2 mid point : $a1 \n"
            break
        elif (( $((a1 -1))==$a2 ))
        then
            printf " $num1 ~ $num2 mid point : $a1 \n"
            break
        fi
    done
fi
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?  I don't know what to do.

Comment: You're missing lots and lots of spaces. Also, you never assign anything to `a1` or `a2`.

Comment: Please fix any errors suggested by shellcheck.net before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You never set a value for `a1`, so the arithmetic statement `(($a1>$a2))` expands to `((>))`. Perhaps you meant `a1=$num1` instead of `num1=$a1`, but you don't need `a1` at all; you can just use `$num1`. The same holds for `a2` and `num2`.